# JavaScript/lodash data transformation

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
var original = {
  "8": [{
      "temp": {
        "a": 1
      },
      "algo_id": 1
    },
    {
      "temp": {
        "a": 2
      },
      "algo_id": 101
    }
  ],
  "13": {
    "temp": {
      "temp1": [1, 2]
    },
    "algo_id": 2
  }
};

const values = _.values(original);
const temp = _.map(values, (v) => {
  if (_.isArray(v)) {
    return _.mapValues(_.keyBy(v, 'algo_id'), a => _.pick(a, 'temp'));
  }
});

console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Expected:

map which has algo_id as key and temp as values.
like below and so on.

```
      {
    "1": {
        "temp": {
            "a": 1
        }
    },
    "101": {
        "temp": {
            "a": 2
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "temp": {
            "temp1": [1, 2]
        }
    }
}
```

How to add key and values which are not array in the object.?

Comment: Your "and so on" is not enough information.  What's the exact output you'd expect for this input?

Comment: updated information expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this (not using lodash) is the following:

```js
const transform = (original) => Object.values(original)
  .flat()
  .reduce((all, {algo_id, ...rest}) => ({...all, [algo_id]: rest}), {})

const original ={"13": {"algo_id": 2, "temp": {"temp1": [1, 2]}}, "8": [{"algo_id": 1, "temp": {"a": 1}}, {"algo_id": 101, "temp": {"a": 2}}]}

console.log(transform(original))
```

But this makes the assumption that you can use the sibling of `algo_id` as is.  Your example seems to show further processing of it that I can't see any rule for.

If your target environments [don't support `flat`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat), you can replace this:

```
      .flat()
```

with this:

```
      .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
```

Comment: hi @Scott, Thanks for your quick response. Just an additional help if you can do quickly then it would be appreciated. From original object, I need records which does not have algo_id.

Comment: and what if algo_id are not part of response? how we can avoid it?

Comment: @JwalinShah: It's not quite clear what you want.  Those two comments sound somewhat contradictory to me.  But if you want to simply skip the elements without `algo_id`, you could add something like this between the `flat` and `reduce` calls: `.filter(o => 'algo_id' in o)`

Comment: One more thing, what if I need only those `algo_id` which has actual something in the value. Like If it has `{}` then I do not want that algoId.

Comment: @JwalinShah: Please start a new question if you have additional concerns.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use lodash, you can do this in plain JavaScript for this.

```js
let original = {
  "8": [{
      "temp": {
        "a": 1
      },
      "algo_id": 1
    },
    {
      "temp": {
        "a": 2
      },
      "algo_id": 101
    }
  ],
  "13": {
    "temp": {
      "temp1": [1, 2]
    },
    "algo_id": 2
  }
};

console.log(convert(original, 'algo_id'));

function convert(data, key) {
  let process = function(value, key, result) {
    result[value[key]] = value;
    delete result[value[key]][key]; // Remove the `algo_id` key
  };
  return Object.keys(data).reduce((result, k, i) => {
    if (Array.isArray(data[k])) {
      data[k].forEach(val => process(val, key, result));
    } else {
      process(data[k], key, result);
    }
    return result;
  }, {});
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<!--

{
    "1": {
        "temp": {
            "a": 1
        }
    }
}

-->
```

Comment: I just need a small help. I do not want the record in the output which does not have algo_id. Currently, it comes with undefined key. and I also want all those objects which does not have algo_id as a seperate variable.

Comment: @JwalinShah The post your FULL expected output, given your input.

Comment: The value of `original["8"]` is an array, as you can see, you need to iterate over it as seen in `if (Array.isArray(data[k]))` above.

Comment: I do not want record in the output which does not have algoId in it. Kindly check the gist link provided.

Comment: Kindly check the link

Comment: @JwalinShah That is not the output you put in your question above.

Answer (score 0):

With lodash, after getting the values, flatten the mixed array of arrays and objects, use keyBy to convert back to an object with the `algo_id` as key, and then map the sub object to omit the `algo_id` property.

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, values, flatten, keyBy, mapValues, omit } = _

const fn = flow(
  values, // convert to a mixed array of objects and arrays
  flatten, // flatten to an array of objects
  pr(keyBy, 'algo_id'), // convert to object with algo_id as key
  pr(mapValues, pr(omit, 'algo_id')), // remove algo_id from the sub objects
);

const original = {"8":[{"temp":{"a":1},"algo_id":1},{"temp":{"a":2},"algo_id":101}],"13":{"temp":{"temp1":[1,2]},"algo_id":2}};

const result = fn(original);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```