# convert map into list of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

Input:

```
{
    "8": [{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    }],
    "13": [{
        "a": 3,
        "b": 4
    }]

}
```

Output

```
[
  {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "type": 8
    },
    {
        "a": 3,
        "b": 4,
        "type": 13
    }
]
```

I tried to do nested map but no luck. Please help if any straightforward way to do it.

```
result = _.map(input, temp => _.map(temp, obj => _.assign(_.pick(obj, ['a', 'b']))));
```

Comment: @JaromandaX lodash map does work on objects

Comment: oh, does it ... my bad

Comment: start with Object.values(" your object") see where that goes I guess...

Comment: your "attempt" is close, except you didn't even "attempt" to add `type` at all ... `result  = _.map(input, (temp, key) => _.map(temp, obj => _.assign({type: +key}, _.pick(obj, ['a', 'b']))))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a technique that should work:

```js
const transform = (input) => Object.entries(input)
  .map(([key, val]) => val.map(v => ({...v, type: key})))
  .flat()

const input = {"13": [{"a": 3, "b": 4}], "8": [{"a": 1, "b": 2}]}

console.log(transform(input))
```

As [pointed out in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291000/1243641), if your target environments [don't support `flat`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-flat), you can replace this:

```
      .flat()
```

with this:

```
      .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.flatMap()` to iterate the object, and flatten the results. Inside the flatMap iterate the values with `_.map()`, and use `_.assign()` to combine the original object and the type:

```js
const input = {
    "8": [{
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    }],
    "13": [{
        "a": 3,
        "b": 4
    }]
}

const result = _.flatMap(input, // iterate the object and flatten the results
  (values, type) => _.map( // iterate the arrays
    values, v => _.assign({ type }, v) // combine the type with the object
  )
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```